# How add to file data? without losing the existing data in the file

Tags: file, blackberry, file-io, java-me, nokia-s40

I use

```
try {           
    DataOutputStream out = c.openDataOutputStream();
        String text = file + " | " + tag + " | " + report + " \n ";
        out.write(text.getBytes());
        out.close();  
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("IOException OutputStream: "+e.getMessage());
    }`
```

but it removes all existing data in the file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using:

```
DataOutputStream out = c.openDataOutputStream(c.fileSize());
```

From the API documentation for openDataOutputStream(long byteOffset)

> byteOffset - number of bytes to skip over from the beginning of the
>   file when positioning the start of the OutputStream. If the provided
>   offset is larger than or equal to the current file size, the
>   OutputStream is positioned at the current end of the file for
>   appending.